# Custom device to be emulated in chrome device emulator

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

I am building a mobile webapp for a 10.1 inch screen tablet with 1900x1200 resolution. The device is an HP Elitepad 1000

I would like to know how to set chrome to emulate the specifications above.

Answer (score 1):

Just press ALT + CMD + I and the Dev.Tools will open.

With SHIFT + CMD + M you switch to the device-emulator.

At "Screen" fill in your resolution. Reload the page for best results.

Comment: sorry wasnt specific about where im getting confused at. 

Do i just put 1900x1200 as that is the resolution? Im confused with screen size and resolution what does the chrome device emulator use as values? What about the device pixel ratio?

Comment: The screen-resolution value is pixel. You cant insert any inch or similar. I don't know the Elitepay pixel-ratio. You should stay with the default of 2.